# Wix Installer -- cannot view Radio Button on dialog

Tags: wix, installation

I am trying to give a choice to the user to choose a mode of authentication with which he/she wants to connect to database. Two choices I am providing are: windows authentication and sql server authentication.

For some reason I am not able to see the radio button on the dialog.

[image: Image showing no radio button]

Dialog code is shown below:

```
<Property Id="CHOICE_WIN_SQL" Value="1" Secure="yes"/>


  <Dialog Id="WinSqlChoiceDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup">
    <Control Type="Text" Width="275" Height="10" X="25" Y="98" Id="TestRadioButton" Text="Radio button should appear below:" />
    <Control Id="AuthenticationType" Property="CHOICE_WIN_SQL" Type="RadioButtonGroup"  X="25" Y="98" Width="300" Height="50">
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="CHOICE_WIN_SQL">
        <RadioButton X="25" Y="110" Value="0" Height="10" Width="275" Text="Windows Authentication"/>
        <RadioButton X="25" Y="123" Value="1" Height="10" Width="275" Text="Sql Authentication"/>
      </RadioButtonGroup>          
    </Control>       
  </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the X and Y values of the RadionButton to the following numbers:

RadioButton X="**0**" Y="**0**"

RadioButton X="**0**" Y="**20**"

So they should look like this:

```
<RadioButton X="0" Y="0" Value="0" Height="10" Width="275" Text="Windows Authentication"/>
<RadioButton X="0" Y="20" Value="1" Height="10" Width="275" Text="Sql Authentication"/>
```

Now the radio buttons will appear but the 'Windows Authentication' radio button will overlap with your label. So change the **Y** value to **50** for example:

```
<Control Type="Text" Width="275" Height="10" X="25" Y="50" Id="TestRadioButton" 
Text="Radio button should appear below:" />
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
<Property Id="CHOICE_WIN_SQL" Value="1" Secure="yes"/>
<Dialog Id="WinSqlChoiceDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup">
<Control Type="Text" Width="275" Height="10" X="25" Y="50" Id="TestRadioButton" Text="Radio button should appear below:" />
<Control Id="AuthenticationType" Property="CHOICE_WIN_SQL" Type="RadioButtonGroup"  X="25" Y="98" Width="300" Height="50">
  <RadioButtonGroup Property="CHOICE_WIN_SQL">
    <RadioButton X="0" Y="0" Value="0" Height="10" Width="275" Text="Windows Authentication"/>
    <RadioButton X="0" Y="20" Value="1" Height="10" Width="275" Text="Sql Authentication"/>
  </RadioButtonGroup>          
</Control>
```

That should do the trick.